# Visiting Indian Formula One circuit in Greater Noida

Tags: india, events, formula-one, grands-prix

The Indian Grand Prix is one of the newest circuit in the F1 Calendar and I want to know:

- Which airport is closest to the circuit?
- Where to stay?
- Is there public transport from/to airport/circuit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The closest useful airport is Delhi's [Indira Gandhi International Airport](http://www.newdelhiairport.in/traveller.aspx) (IATA code DEL, 60km by road). There are other airports in the region but none of them are serviced by regular commercial flights.
2. The [Indian GP](http://buddhinternationalcircuit.in/) circuit is in a town called [Greater Noida](https://www.google.com/maps/@28.3522484,77.5313176,12.81z), which lies on the outskirts of New Delhi. As such, there are *plenty* of [places to stay in Delhi](http://www.booking.com/city/in/new-delhi.en-gb.html?aid=356980;label=gog235jc-city-XX-in-newNdelhi-unspec-gb-com-L%3Aen-O%3Aunk-B%3Aunk-N%3AXX-S%3Abo-U%3AXX;sid=56b832e6d38309e2c33edb6a39dfd935;dcid=1;inac=0&), so this question is too broad.
3. Taking public transport to the Indian GP circuit is not recommended and possibly doesn't exist. While public transport *within* New Delhi is reasonably good - thanks to a metro and public bus system, along with 'autorickshaws' and taxis - public transport from Delhi to surrounding towns such as Gurgaon, Noida, Greater Noida, et al is infrequent and quite bad. Even if you do find a bus to Greater Noida, these outlying townships don't have good public transport available for intra-city travel, so it's kinda pointless.

Fortunately, it won't be too expensive to hire a taxi to take you to the Indian GP circuit from Delhi. Getting to Greater Noida requires you to take a tolled expressway anyway, which is typically not serviced by public buses. Make sure you don't get ripped off by the taxi driver by agreeing on a price beforehand, if you can.

Comment: the New Delhi smog was awful for watching

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the answer, the newly opened [Yamuna Expressway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamuna_Expressway) offers speedy access from the city to Greater Noida and beyond to Agra. The Buddh International Circuit is conveniently located just off the highway. The toll to get from the city to the circuit is Rs. 320, and probably takes about 20-30 minutes - a much-needed improvement over the existing route.
In the absence of public transit facilities, prepaid taxis would likely be the most comfortable and economical to get there.

Comment: Better to add as a comment on an answer, if it's not a separate answer.